# Strange behaviour from System.IO.DirectoryInfo. Exists function

Tags: c#, asp.net, io, directoryinfo

I am developing an application using c# and asp.  It need to access some places in the local network . There is a text box in the form which accept the path to be accessed from the user and will store it to a string variable named location.

The if loop always return false if the application run in windows 7. and  it occurs only when I run from the installed application, otherwise it will return true if the path is true. Here is the code:

The input to textbox BackupLocation is like this

```
 \\192.168.0.33\Others (F)
```

. It work fine  if the  application is hosted on a system   which have windows XP

```
 System.IO.DirectoryInfo locationInfo = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(BackupLocationTxt.Text);
        if (locationInfo.Exists) // always return false  if the application run in windows 7
       {

       }
```

Why this happens ?

Comment: How are you creating the string `location`? When on ASP you should use `Server.MapPath(string)` to get the *actual* location on disk instead of one relative to your web application path. Can this be the issue?

Comment: Please  look at the edited question

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the user you are running your application under doesn't have authorization to read those folders. You might need to grant read access to those folders to the account you are running your site under.

Comment: Its work fine in windows xp .How can i give permission if the application run in windows 7.and the folder have read and write permissions to EVERYONE

Comment: Where is this application hosted? IIS, Cassini, ...?

Comment: the applications is hosted in IIS

Comment: IIS7, integrated mode, classic mode? Under which account is the application pool configured?

Comment: the application is running  in under ASPNET account . and it is hosted in IIS7

Answer (score 1):

Try `System.IO.Directory.Exists(string path)` instead.

Comment: Is this a suggestion or a solution? How would this help?

Comment: This was somehow a solution to my case. DirectoryInfo.Exists always returned false, when Directory.Exists(DirectoryInfo.FullName) always returned true. But I still don't get why the one works over the other ?!

Answer (score 0):

Your ASP.NET application doesn't have permissions to the folder on other computer in local network.

Try use windows service started under LocalService account.